# How to switch between mongoDB connection using Laravel jensseger/mongodb library?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using this library (the older version compatible with Laravel 9).

This is my connection string.

```
'mongodb' => [
      'driver'   => 'mongodb',
      'host'     => env('MONGODB_HOST', 'localhost'),
      'port'     => env('MONGODB_PORT', 27017),
      'database' => env('MONGODB_DATABASE'),
      'username' => env('MONGODB_USERNAME'),
      'password' => env('MONGODB_PASSWORD'),
      'options'  => [
                'database' => env('MONGODB_DATABASE')
      ]
],
```

The idea is, when a new vendor would register, a new database would be created. Now when I want to switch between DB's I am doing this:-

```
DB::disconnect('mongodb'); // Connection name
DB::purge('mongodb');
Config::set('database.connections.mongodb.database', $databaseName);
Config::set('database.connections.mongodb.options.database', $databaseName);
DB::reconnect('mongodb');
```

This one gives me the list of all DBs.

```
$data = DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoClient()->listDatabases();
print_r($data);
```

How can I get the DB of the current connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the connection class i see a public method `getDatabaseName()`, so if your database creation is set up correctly you should see the database name with:

```
$dbName = DB::connection('mongodb')->getDatabaseName();
//or
$dbName = DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
```

I guess you can/should log in as a vendor and check that you are connected to the correct database